# How configure properly vncserver in Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5

Tags: linux, fonts, x11, redhat, vnc-server

I'm trying to start `vncserver` in a `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5` with an user created for that, and when I type `vncserver` I got this:

```
WARNING: The first attempt to start Xvnc failed, possibly because the font catalog is not properly configured.
Attempting to determine an appropriate font path for this system and restart Xvnc using that font path ...
Could not start Xvnc.

Xvnc TigerVNC 1.3.1 - built Mar 19 2014 12:23:33
Copyright (C) 1999-2011 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.txt)
See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 11300000, The X.Org Foundation

Initializing built-in extension VNC-EXTENSION
Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension XVideo
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
Initializing built-in extension GLX

Thu Apr 16 13:39:57 2015
vncext:      VNC extension running!
vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5901
vncext:      Listening for HTTP connections on all interface(s), port 5801
vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
[dix] Could not init font path element catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element built-ins, removing from list!

Fatal server error:
could not open default font 'fixed'

Xvnc TigerVNC 1.3.1 - built Mar 19 2014 12:23:33
Copyright (C) 1999-2011 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.txt)
See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 11300000, The X.Org Foundation

Initializing built-in extension VNC-EXTENSION
Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension XVideo
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
Initializing built-in extension GLX

Thu Apr 16 13:40:00 2015
vncext:      VNC extension running!
vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5901
vncext:      Listening for HTTP connections on all interface(s), port 5801
vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/X11/fonts/misc, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/X11/fonts/75dpi, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/X11/fonts/100dpi, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/X11/fonts/Type1, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/misc, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Type1, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element built-ins, removing from list!

Fatal server error:
could not open default font 'fixed'
```

I'm looking for the resolution but I'm unable to find the one to solve this, can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.
Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finllay I had to download the Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server ISO and create a local repo with these instructions:

```
# mkdir /media/rhel6
# mount -o loop rhel-server-6.5-x86_64-dvd.iso /media/rhel6/
# head -n1 /media/rhel6/.discinfo => Note down the number
# nano /etc/yum.repos.d/rhel6.repo
```

In `rhel6.repo` we have to add:

```
[rhel6-Server]
mediaid=(Number previously noted)
name=RHEL6-Server
baseurl=file:///media/rhel6/Server
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```

With this we have already our repository. Now we're going to install the neccesary packages:

```
yum update
```

If we did this and shows somethin like this:

```
...
file:///mnt/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Could not open/read file:///mnt/repodata/repomd.xml
...
```

We have to disable other repos in your system by setting `enabled` variable in `/etc/yum.repos.d/other-repos.repo` to `0`.

Then we have to install the following `groupinstall`:

```
# yum --skip-broken -y groupinstall "X Window System"
# yum --skip-broken -y groupinstall "Desktop"
# yum --skip-broken -y groupinstall "Fonts"
```

That's it, we can already use vncserver.

Greetings.